# Crashlytics Crash In Eclipse - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]

Tags: android, eclipse, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have searched far and wide for this issue, but have not found a solution yet. I have an Android app (Cocos2dx) built with Eclipse (Mars) in C++.
While I know Fabric has stopped support for Eclipse, I am unable to move the project to Android Studio (I am not using Gradle either).
I have managed to add Fabric and Crashlytics into my project(including additions to the manifest, custom_rules and the likes) and have solved all the compilation issues regarding those two.
Whenever I run my app, it crashes on startup, with the following exception:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit[]
W/System.err( 9858):    at com.infiapps.slotbonanza.SlotBonanza.onCreate(SlotBonanza.java:203)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 9858):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
W/System.err( 9858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 9858):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 9858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
W/System.err( 9858):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
W/System.err( 9858):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

I saw other posts suggesting using MultiDex and I have tried solving my issue with that. I have also tried adding the Crashlytics.jar file into my build path, but that has not worked as well. 
From reading other posts and looking online, I am aware this issue occurs because the Crashlytics libraries are found during compile time, but not during runtime.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.